# Is there only one holomorphically induced parametrization $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

A function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is called a parametrization if for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ there exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $n=f^{\circ k}(0)$.

A function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is said to be holomorphically induced if there is an elementary entire function $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})\subset \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $g|_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}=f$.

Is $f(n)=n+1$ the only holomorphically induced parametrization?

Comment: For any sequence $f(n)$ take $h(z)$ entire such that $|f(n)/h(n)|$ is bounded, then $g(z)=e^{z^2} h(z)\sum_n \frac{f(n)}{h(n)}e^{-n^2}\frac{\sin(\pi (z-n))}{\pi (z-n)} $  is entire and $g(n)=f(n)$. Let $f^{\circ k}(0)$ be any enumeration of $\Bbb{Z}$, this defines some $f$ uniquely.